# Spring - Error al inyectar un DAO en una clase Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Espero me puedan ayudar, les comento, tengo 2 proyectos:
El primero es una API que recibirá peticiones y la segunda es un proyecto que busco reutilizar en otros proyectos (como una librería).

### Proyecto de librerías:

*Estructura del proyecto librería*

[image: Estructura del proyecto librería]

*La clase DAO*

[image: La clase DAO]

*La clase Service*

[image: La clase Service]

### Proyecto API

*Estrucura del proyecto API*

[image: Estrucura del proyecto API]

*SpringBoot*

[image: SpringBoot]

*StoreController*

[image: StoreController]

Mi problema es que cuando trato de iniciar el proyecto me bota un error diciendo que la clase **StoreService** no puede inyectar **IStoreDao**

*Description:
Field storeDao in com.cmrv.library.common.model.store.service.impl.StoreService required a bean of type 'com.cmrv.library.common.model.store.dao.IStoreDao' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.cmrv.library.common.model.store.dao.IStoreDao' in your configuration.*

Le he dado varias vueltas y no se porque me está apareciendo este error.
Ojalá me puedan ayudar a solucionar esto.
Gracias.

Comment: IStoreDao es una interface. Spring necesita conocer una implementación de IStoreDao, es decir, una clase que implemente IStoreDao con el fin de poderla instanciar.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar la anotación @Repository o @Component. Repository es justamente para declarar DAOs. Como dice la documentación, la anotación es una especializacion de @Component.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html

Para que pueda ser detectada como un componente dentro del spring context.

```
@Repository
public interface IStoreDao extends MongoRepository<Store, String> {}
```